# for loop to consider one even value and one odd value

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a dataset which have latitude and longitude values . I have separated them into even positions and odd positions.I want to consider if first even value must be taken with only the first value of odd.

But my for loop considers one value of even with all the value of odd and then does the save thing for all.

As I have return a function for the attribute cooords.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("/home/even_odd.csv")
even=df[::2]
odd = df.iloc[1::2]
for row in even.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    lat1=getattr(row, "lat")
    lng1=getattr(row, "lon")
    for row in odd.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    lat2=getattr(row, "lat")
    lng2=getattr(row, "lon")
    print("/////-------------")
    azimuth = calculateBearing(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    azimuth
    coords = main(interval,azimuth,lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2)
    print(coords)
```

I want a for loop to consider the first value of even dataframe with only the the first value of odd dataframe and then so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to loop through odd and even simultaneously:

```
for (rowEven, rowOdd) in zip (even.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'), odd.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas')):
    # do additional works
    lat1=getattr(rowEven, "lat")
    lng1=getattr(rowEven, "lon")
    lat2=getattr(rowOdd, "lat")
    lng2=getattr(rowOdd, "lon")
```

Comment: I have a question.....while printing the variable coords it gives me 10 sets of list but while saving it into csv it just provides me only the last list .....why?@Asif

Comment: that happens because every time coords variable is overridden inside the for loop. To save all data you need to save coords into another list then write that new list into csv file

Comment: how can i proceed to do that@Asif

Comment: add an empty list named "newList" before the for loop: newList = []
then before print(coords) add : newList.append(coords)
then write this newList into csv

Comment: but getting the list as a row how can i transpose it into columns while saving @Asif